# Drawing Line Over The Button - Android

Tags: android, drawing

This may very simple question but i don't know how to draw line dynamically OVER the Button without using Surface view holder etc..

I am new to android programming and java also..
I am just trying to make an simple game (Cross and Zero).

All things are done, but only thing what i can not do is Drawing line over the button while winning condition in the game..

I know it can be done with the use of Canvas and Paint or something but i don't know how to do it !

Can anyone describe how to do it ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: is it imporataint to use the button? may be just you need the coordinates on the drawable?

Comment: I have used buttons.. I have set onclick for buttons and also i m changing text of button and checking condition about win or lose or tie.. So in this app buttons are very useful to me...

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this too, here's a simple way to draw a line on a button:
First create a blank .png I just opened microsoft paint and saved it blank button sized.
Save it in the res/drawable-mdpi, then go in there and rename it with .png
Now in your XML add this to your button: android:background="@drawable/untitled"
My bitmap was called untitled.png but you have to leave out the .png in XML
Now in your source code add this (where NB is Your button):

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
NB.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
Paint paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 100, paint);
```

Comment: Sorry my post was premature.  The XML part was of no use for me, and if I did use a real image which I think Eagle_Eye is, it disapeared and replaced it with just the line.

Answer (score 1):

Just Google some samples about 2d-graphics. IMHO you need custom view and ontouch listener

try something like this: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_2D.html

Comment: Thanks trololo.. But in this tutorial they have set a view in setContentView(), which is what i don't want.. if i set a view in setContentView() then what about my layout which i have set already in onCreate() ? And what is IMHO ?